# Laravel Global Scope Composite Indexing Issue

Tags: php, laravel

When applying Global Scope to a Model, the applied Scope gets appended to the end of the Query Builder.

I am looking for a way to append the Scope at the start of the query builder.
Like the very first where the condition for any query.

Appreciate Your Time!

**Query Returned:**

```
select * from banners where locale = ? and tenant_id = ?
```

**Query Expected:**

```
select * from banners where tenant_id = ? and locale = ?
```

Comment: Does sorting **where clauses**  make any difference in results or performance ?

Comment: Yes brother. You should read about how indexes work :)